# Where can I find visual examples of the thought process behind different logo designs?

Tags: logo, grids, design-process

In this image you can see a preliminary grid and then circles are added that are aligned with the grid and then the shapes are formed by the intersecting circles, etc:

[image]

I'm looking for some examples like this.  Even works in progress and logos that didn't make the cut are ok.  I'm trying to understand the thought process behind logo design.

Comment: These are sketches, which, is the tool behind the thought process behind logo design. Typically lots of sketches. Lots and lots and lots and lots and lots of sketches.

Comment: Related: [What is this circle technique called?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/25143/23061)

Answer (score 9):

Specially if you work on your own and you haven't done that many logos, the process can be quite straightforward: One or two main ideas, some alternative executions, and a final agreement. Maybe you are happy with the result, maybe it doesn't really seem to mean that much.

When I came across these examples about a year ago (had to regoogle it), it completely changed the way I looked at logo design. I think you will find them useful too:

[From Concept to Completion: 50 Examples of the Logo Design Process](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/inspiration/50-concept-completion-logo/).

[image]

> Creating an effective and successful logo design is both an art and a
>   science. The process of logo design is a coming together of the
>   innovative as well as the technical.

I specially liked the Vividwaves and Metro Aviation articles, I recommend you check those. Quite inspiring!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out a keyword to search by and found some great examples on dribbble:

http://dribbble.com/search?q=construct

Comment: Note that those, in general, are 'construction lines' so not necessarily part of the *design* thought process as much as the *production* methodology. But also keep in mind that on a site like Dribbble, a lot of those construction lines aren't even part of the production methodology and are merely stylistic elements add after the fact for presentation flair.