# Geometric circles gridding/guidelines workflow illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, grids, guides

does anyone here have any advice or know of any good resources/video tutorials, that would demonstrate how to work with circles & grids in a nice easy workflow. I saw something about using plugins from astute graphics though I am totally new to those tools. I've attached an image to help demonstrate what I mean.

[image]

Comment: Related, possble duplicate: [What is this circle technique called?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/25143/52050) (knew I'd seen that image somewhere)

Comment: Not sure specifically, geometric gridding would be my best guess!

Comment: That is a link to a related previous Q&A not question from me btw :)

Comment: Jesus sorry, what a noobish thing to do haha (first post here forgive me)

Comment: haha no problem!

Answer (score 1):

this design would begin as a sketch that has developed over multiple observations and refinements - then the circles are grouped and placed in illustrator (in a layer/s) to minimise non-essential shapes. Your right brain will start to take over and you will be able to visualise your desired  design emerging - like watching clouds as they blow overhead for into recognisable animal shapes or the like. Feel the Force.