# Logo construction (grid?)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, grids

I'm trying to figure out how this logo was constructed but I can't make sense of the highlighted (in pink) circles... Can anyone tell me how that was made? I'm looking for an Adobe Illustrator solution, please!!

[image: Logo]

Notice that, in fact, what I really want to know is how to align the shapes in the manner of the image shown (left side). I think this could be a particular approach in Design because I've seen it in other logos and icons, but my concern here is with the technical aspect of alignment in Adobe Illustrator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is this circle technique called?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/25143/what-is-this-circle-technique-called)

Comment: Also [Geometric circles gridding/guidelines workflow illustrator](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/79050/52050)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this.

1. draw line from opposite small circle to line large circle intersection.
2. Rotate copy of that line vertical
3. Make a support snapping line horizontal to the rotated lines end
4. draw circle form construction line crossing to support line
5. mirror, cleanup

[image]

Alternate construction strategy.

1. Enable grid
2. draw a 3 units wide/high circle
3. draw a 1 unit wide/high circle
4. draw a 2 unit wide circle
5. move the circles so the t the 3/1 unit circles share center and center of 2 unit circle is on edge of 1 unit circle

   [image]

   **Image 2**: Circle construction
6. Rotate entire thing 45 degrees (this helps you optimize point count)
7. duplicate a 45 degree turn copy of 2 unit circle.

Comment: Woah! Thanks A LOT. Your first instructions did work but I couldn't manage to snap everything correctly, however the second, with the grid on and grid snapping on, I could FINALLY make it!! XD Thanks a lot, again!! Perfect snapping, no gaps. By the way, how did you figure it out? Do you have any interesting reference where I can learn more about this, please??

Comment: Actually, with the second technique I can't seem to have a larger circle in the middle... But your direction seems correct! I'll keep working on it!

Comment: @prubini87 you are snapping to intersections?

Comment: I'm trying to but how can I click those intersections correctly? My click is always a little off... :/ [http://imgur.com/a/wBP6U](http://imgur.com/a/wBP6U) - Thanks for your time!

Comment: You need to enable smart guides, and you need to disable grid snapping and pixel snapping

Comment: So, I have Smart Guides on and all snapping off, but still, when I try to click an intersection of two paths, it doesn't highlight something like "intersection"... I got a "path" smart guide but I think it's only indicating that my mouse is over one of the two paths because when I click it and zoom in in outline mode it's always a little off... ://...Should smart guides indicate the point where two segments/paths intersect, even if there's no actual anchor point there?

Comment: @purbin try holding control or alt. Or you need to adjust your smartguides setting in the options to be less sensitive. Yes it should snap to intersection without any points. When it does it says intersection ane highlights both paths.

Comment: Yep, I've just figured my snapping tolerance was at 0pt, so I've changed it to 4pt and now smart guides are showing a lot more information!! ;DD Thanks!!

Comment: So here's my progress: [http://imgur.com/a/QqBXQ](http://imgur.com/a/QqBXQ). I try to draw the "medium" circle from an intersection holding Alt+Shift but I can only do it until it snaps to the bottom of our "guiding line" (the one we drew from 45 degree angle, then I pull it to the top holding Shift, but then I get that weird space between the circles. Any ideas @joojaa?